# Please explain what this piece of C code does

Tags: c

Can someone explain what is this piece of code do?

```
pa_offset = offset & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);

/* offset for mmap() must be page aligned */
```

I understand that here `sysconf` returns the page size, which lets assume that it is 4096, but after that I am not able to understand the logic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming page size is a power of 2, the expression will return `offset % _SC_PAGE_SIZE`; so if offset is 5000 and page size is 4096 it will return 4.

**update:** i was wrong, see comments below.  also the context as requested by OP is of virtual address to physical address translation in an operating system. the expression above gives the virtual page address, which is translated into a physical page address. after translation the byte being addressed is found at page_address + (offset % _SC_PAGE_SIZE).

Comment: No, it returns `offset - (offset % _SC_PAGE_SIZE)`, so if `offset` is 5000 and the page size is 4096, it will set `pa_offset` to 4096.

Comment: @agks mehx: did you mean 904 instead of 4? I am not getting the same answer for both, can you please verify it again?

Comment: @caf: Ya that works, can you explain why is it used here(in context of the information provided in the comment in the question)?

Comment: @hue, @caf is right.  the context is of virtual address to physical address translation in an operating system.  the expression above gives the virtual page address, which is translated into a physical page address.  after translation the byte being addressed is found at page_address + (offset % _SC_PAGE_SIZE).

Comment: @hue: It appears to be converting an offset into a file into a page-aligned offset - that is, an offset that is a multiple of the page size.  This is done in preparation for a call to `mmap()`, because the offset passed to that function must be page-aligned.

Comment: @caf: Thanks, that was helpful. Ya it is done in preparation for a call to mmap(). Hey caf can you suggest some good reference that I can study to become a good system developer, as I m a fresher and working in system software field.

Answer (score 9):

If `sysconf` returns the page size, which is a power of two or `00..00100..00` in binary, `- 1` makes a mask of that number (that is, it makes a number of the form `00..0011..11`, then `~` computes the reverse of this mask (`11..1100..00`). Lastly, the bitwise and `&` operation between the newly created mask and `offset` rounds `offset` down to the nearest multiple of the page size.

Answer (score 3):

4096 is 2<sup>12</sup>, so `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1` is 12 1's in binary. The complement (`~`) is a series of leading 1's followed by 12 0's. `offset & 1111...0000 0000 0000` will therefore extract the bits used to represent the page number.